# Maven test failing: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I am trying to set up tests using Maven. I am getting the following error while trying to run the command "mvn test":

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/dso/Documents/Eclipse-Workspace/MavenSample/src/test/java/MavenSample/MavenSample/RestAPITest.java:[3,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: package org.testng.annotations
```

Both mvn clean and mvn compile works fine for me with no errors. Also the test itself runs fine if it is ran as just testng. The test fails when mvn test is done. Below is the code for my pom.xml file.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>MavenSample</groupId>
 <artifactId>MavenSample</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>MavenSample</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>


 <build>
   <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
 </build>


<dependencies>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.0-beta4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->

   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: maybe your class RestAPITest has a compile error. Can you show us this class ?

Comment: can you remove junit dependency . Only keep testNG?

Comment: There is no proper code in the test. It is just a sample file:

Comment: `package MavenSample.MavenSample;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RestAPITest {
 
 @Test
 public void PostJIRA()
 {
  System.out.println("PostJIRA");
 }
 
 @Test
 public void DeleteTwitter()
 {
  System.out.println("DeleteTwitter");
 }

}` . @MychellTeixeira

Comment: Still getting the same error @QingfeiYuan

Comment: @SUPARNASOMAN  don't forget refresh your project after your changing pom file.

Comment: @QingfeiYuan Not working still

Comment: Try to remove this import import org.testng.annotations.Test; and use this import org.junit.Test;

Comment: Note that tests must be in src/test/java, not src/main/java. Eclipse doesn’t care, maven does.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen test is inside src/test/java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the library is needed in compilation time, and you only specified to "test" scope.

Try to change this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.14.3</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

[UPDATED] in the beta version you are using, there is no Test annotation in the package "org.testng.annotations".

Answer (score 1):

Thank You So Much! After struggling a week with spending hours searching for the answer finally i was able to resolve the issue. I was having the same exact problem as mentioned in the questions. The fix was changing the xml dependency. Previously it was like this:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-beta4</version>
</dependency>
```

I changed the XML to This:----->

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```